# Calling Class method via Rails ActiveRecord Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have two classes as:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  # Class method
  # does some analysis on all the comments of a given post  
  def self.do_sentiment_analysis
     post_id = self.new.post_id  # Is there a better way to get post_id?

     # real code that does something follows

  end

end


# Class method is called on a post object like this:
Post.find(1).comments.do_sentiment_analysis
```

The question is whether there is a better way to know the id of the association object (post) on which the class method is called. One way (which is used above) is: `post_id = self.new.post_id`. 
I bet there is a cleaner way where I don't have to create an object just to get the `post_id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question directly,

```
Comment.scope_attributes
```

Will return a hash of those attributes the current scope on Comment would set. You can test the effect an association has on this like so

I'm not sure I'd use this though - it seems a little odd to have a class method that can only be invoked on scopes of a particular form.

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for. A replacement of `post_id = self.new.post_id` which (as you suggested): `post_id=Comment.scope_attributes["post_id"]`.

So far as why am I doing it, it might come handy in cases where you want to do some processing of all the comments for a post and would like to call `post.find(1).comments.process_comments`. This `process_comments` can be a class method for `Comment`. Though not necessary, but possibly I'd want to know which "owner" called this association - and this is where the question comes in.

Answer (score 3):

The sentiment analysis is an important business logic of yours, and maybe it will grow a lot, so I think is better to put it in it's own class.

If you do so, you will be capable of just pass a post to the Analyzer (for example):

```
# app/models/analyzer.rb
class Analyzer
  def initialize(post)
    @post = post
  end

  def sentiment
    @post.comments.each do |comment|
      do_something_with comment
      # ... more real stuff here
    end
  end

  def some_other_analysis
  end

  private
  def do_something_with(comment)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Now you would be able to rewrite your example:

```
Analyzer.new(Post.find(1)).sentiment
```

Comment: Appears to me that this is a good way to go because it will show to the future you (the one who have written the code) and for the possible code maintainers that stumble upon the code, a "right" place to put the analytic logic. I'm NOT advocating against put some logic on your Active Record model (Comment in this case), I'm just suggesting that this is a specific logic that would benefit from a proper place to grow.

Comment: Is there a way to get the ID of the associated object other than `post_id = self.new.post_id` ? This is just a sample code. The real code doesn't do any sentiment analysis. There is a very small processing done on all the comments of a post, hence doesn't warrant a new class. Again we don't even need the post ID to iterate over the comments. This question is for curiosity of how can we get the associated object's id when a static method is called in this way